# How conditionally test the selected option/value from a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I have a currency-picker drop-down list, that works fine, 
but I now need to compare the selected currency to the shop.currency
and I don't know how to get it compare.

The drop-down code is:

```
<label class="currency-picker__wrapper">
  <span class="currency-picker__label">Pick a currency</span>
  <select class="currency-picker" name="currencies" style="display: inline; width: auto; vertical-align: inherit;">
    <option value="GBP" selected="selected">GBP</option>
    <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
    ...
    <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

I now need to display a message if they select the shop.currency
and a different message if they select other currencies.

I currently display the selected currency with the following html:

```
<p>
  Your cart is currently displayed in
  <span class="selected-currency"></span>,
  you will check out using {{ shop.currency }} at today's exchange rate.
</p>
```

And the following javascript code:

```
jQuery('[name=currencies]').val(Currency.currentCurrency).change(function() {
  var newCurrency = jQuery(this).val();
  Currency.convertAll(Currency.currentCurrency, newCurrency);
  jQuery('.selected-currency').text(Currency.currentCurrency);
```

So I can OUTPUT the selected option into a `<div>`, but I don't know how to get it into the form whereby I can conditionally compare it.

So I don't know how to construct:

```
If selectedCurrency = shop.currency
message1
else
message2
endif
```

??

I tried using:

```
var e = document.getElementById("currency-picker__wrapper");
var selectedCurrency = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

But without success.
Your guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, `newCurrency` seems to contain your currently selected currency. So compare that whatever `shop.currency` is?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the missing parts of your code snippet actually works, with the given info, there is no html element with `id = currency-picker__wrapper`. Please add this to your select list `<select class="currency-picker" id='currency-picker__wrapper'...` or just any unique id so `document.getElementById()` can return the element.

Cannot comment on the rest of it with the given info. Hope it helps.